# Optimizing SQL Server stored procedures that use functions?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, query-optimization

I'd like some help in optimizing the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@NumberOfResultsRequested) dbo.FilterRecentSearchesTitles(OriginalSearchTerm) AS SearchTerms
FROM UserSearches
WHERE WebsiteID = @WebsiteID
AND LEN(OriginalSearchTerm) > 20
--AND dbo.FilterRecentSearchesTitles(OriginalSearchTerm) NOT IN (SELECT KeywordUrl FROM PopularSearchesBaseline WHERE WebsiteID = @WebsiteID)
GROUP BY OriginalSearchTerm, GeoID
```

It runs fine without the line that is commented out.  I have an index set on UserSearches.OriginalSearchTerm, WebsiteID, and PopularSearchesBaseline.KeywordUrl, but the query still runs slow with this line in there.

-- UPDATE -- 
The function used is as follows:

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FilterRecentSearchesTitles]
(
    @SearchTerm VARCHAR(512)
)

RETURNS VARCHAR(512)

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret VARCHAR(512)

    SET @Ret = dbo.RegexReplace('[0-9]', '', REPLACE(@SearchTerm, '__s', ''), 1, 1)
    SET @Ret = dbo.RegexReplace('\.', '', @Ret, 1, 1)
    SET @Ret = dbo.RegexReplace('\s{2,}', ' ', @Ret, 1, 1)
    SET @Ret = dbo.RegexReplace('\sv\s', ' ', @Ret, 1, 1)

    RETURN(@Ret)
END
```

Using the [Reglar Expression Workbench](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/) code.

However, as I mentioned - without the line that is currently commented out it runs fine.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Remove the function. Or show us what the function does. If it does data access for every line in the source query, I think we found your problem. Consider re-writing it as a table-valued function, then SQL Server has some chance at optimizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using using the function on `SELECT`, I modified the `INSERT` query to include this function.  That way, I avoid calling the function for every row when I later want to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to guess that `dbo.FilterRecentSearchesTitles(OriginalSearchTerm)` is a function.  My suggestion would be to see about rewriting it into a [table valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) so you can return a table that could be joined on.

Otherwise you are calling that function for each row you are trying to return which is going to cause your problems.

If you cannot rewrite the function, then why not create a stored proc that will only execute it once, similar to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@NumberOfResultsRequested) dbo.FilterRecentSearchesTitles(OriginalSearchTerm) AS SearchTerms
INTO #temp
WHERE WebsiteID = @WebsiteID


SELECT *
FROM #temp
WHERE SearchTerms NOT IN (SELECT KeywordUrl 
                            FROM PopularSearchesBaseline 
                            WHERE WebsiteID = @WebsiteID)
```

Then you get your records into a temp table after executing the function once and then you select on the temp table.

Comment: Based on your suggestion of the function being called on every function, I modified my row insert to include this function, adding the content to a new column.  That way, I can avoid having to do this later for every row on the SELECT. +1 for putting me on a better track.

Answer (score 1):

I might try to use a [persisted computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) in this case:

```
ALTER TABLE UserSearches ADD FilteredOriginalSearchTerm AS dbo.FilterRecentSearchesTitles(OriginalSearchTerm) PERSISTED
```

You will probably have to add `WITH SCHEMABINDING` to your function (and the RegexReplace function) like so:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FilterRecentSearchesTitles]
(
    @SearchTerm VARCHAR(512)
)

RETURNS VARCHAR(512)

WITH SCHEMABINDING -- You will need this so the function is considered deterministic

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret VARCHAR(512)

    SET @Ret = dbo.RegexReplace('[0-9]', '', REPLACE(@SearchTerm, '__s', ''), 1, 1)
    SET @Ret = dbo.RegexReplace('\.', '', @Ret, 1, 1)
    SET @Ret = dbo.RegexReplace('\s{2,}', ' ', @Ret, 1, 1)
    SET @Ret = dbo.RegexReplace('\sv\s', ' ', @Ret, 1, 1)

    RETURN(@Ret)
END
```

This makes your query look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@NumberOfResultsRequested) FilteredOriginalSearchTerm AS SearchTerms
FROM UserSearches
WHERE WebsiteID = @WebsiteID
AND LEN(OriginalSearchTerm) > 20
AND FilteredOriginalSearchTerm NOT IN (SELECT KeywordUrl FROM PopularSearchesBaseline WHERE WebsiteID = @WebsiteID)
GROUP BY OriginalSearchTerm, GeoID
```

Which could potentially be optimized for speed (if necessary) with a join instead of `not in`, or maybe different indexing (perhaps on the computed column, or some covering indexes).  Also, `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is somewhat of a code smell to me, but it could be legit.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the DISTINCT and GROUP BY... they're just artifacts of different iterations.  Thanks for the suggestions.